# How to create and then write text into a file in Jenkins using Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I write a Jjenkins job, which can firstly create a CODEOWNER file direct in workspace and then write a text into this file.

I have tried:

```
node {
    writeFile file: 'groovy1.txt', text: 'Working with files the Groovy way is easy.'
    sh 'ls -l groovy1.txt'
    sh 'cat groovy1.txt'
}
```

However, the above code was not working.

While building, the job was stopping.

I have read the documentation Groovy. There is a method called `writeFile(file, text)`, this `writeFile` method overwrites the text, if this method in a loop. My goal is: insert text into the file but this text is a string. I am not sure it is right syntax for CODEOWNERS.

Any solution?

Comment: "the job was stopping" isn't enough info. Please add the relevant parts of your build's Console Output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new too using Jenkins and Groovy, and as I can see, scripts like yours seems to works inside the script{} statement. It works for me in this way:

```
    stage('My Stage'){
      steps{
            ...
            script{
                   writeFile file: 'groovy1.txt', text: 'Working with files the Groovy way is easy.'
                   sh 'ls -l groovy1.txt'
                   sh 'cat groovy1.txt' 
            }
       }
    }
```